# JavaScript Button Pressed Only Once

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make it so that using the code below, you can only click the button once, before it doesn't do anything. Thanks in advance!

```
 <button onClick="yumpizza();"style="position:absolute; TOP:120px; LEFT:350px">Roll for strength</button>

<script>
    var strength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
    function yumpizza() {
    document.getElementById("pizza").innerHTML = ("Strength:" + strength)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make onclick function execute only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57641554/how-to-make-onclick-function-execute-only-once)

Comment: Using addEventListener you could also usw the {once} Option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the onclick event of the element to null after the first trigger:

```
<button id="pizzaButton" onClick="yumpizza();" style="position:absolute; TOP:120px; LEFT:350px">Roll for strength</button>

<script>
  var strength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
  function yumpizza() {
    document.getElementById("pizza").innerHTML = ("Strength:" + strength);
    document.getElementById("pizzaButton").onclick = null;
  }
</script>
```

On the note of event handling, is is a best practice to use `addEventListener` to set event handlers programmatically, instead of the `onclick` HTML attribute.

Comment: @ProVideoCreator you have to accept the answer newbie ;)

Comment: @ProVideoCreator Don't forget to accept it as the answer if it fixed your problem. Also, you may want to try using the `disabled` attribute instead, since it alters the styling of the button.

Comment: better coding practice to make the button disabled. this gives a visual cue to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Add one more line to yumpizza() function:

```
document.getElementById("pizzaButton").disabled = true;
```

Comment: this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use jquery:

```
    var strength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
    function yumpizza() {
    document.getElementById("pizza").innerHTML = ("Strength:" + strength)
}
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).disable();
});
```

here is the fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/tnaZV/530/

Comment: I don't really like jQuery that much, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
const button = document.querySelector("#pizzaButton"); 

button.addEventListener("click", ev => { ev.currentTarget.textContent}, { once: true });
```

// or 1: event.currentTarget.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
// 2: button.currentTarget.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
var strength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
function yumpizza() { 
document.getElementById("pizza").innerHTML = ("Strength:" + strength);
document.getElementById("pizza").disabled = true;
}
</script>
```