# How to make my button clickable only once?

Tags: javascript

I have a button. I need to make it clickable only once. But it does not have onclick attribute. And I cannot change HTML. This has to be done only with JS. How do I do it?

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="41" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">
  BUY NOW
</button>
```

Comment: disable the button after the click ... use on click handler...

Comment: You can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57641554/how-to-make-onclick-function-execute-only-once

Comment: it's silly, it is not by disabling a submit button that we can prevent the sending of a form. Any return on an input allows to send a submit

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a `click` handler to the button and set its `disabled` property to `true`:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button[name="add-to-cart"]');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  button.disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="41" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">BUY NOW</button>
```

If you ever need to *re-enable* the button, that would be additional logic of course.  But it looks like this button is intended to submit a form which will change the page context anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can an event listener ('click') and change add the attribute. After that, remove the event listener.